# Quantile regression for panel data software

Tags: r, panel-data, quantile-regression

I have 100 observations across time for 200 units. I have 1 continuous dependent variable and 5 independent variables. Can I do quantile regression for this panel dataset? If yes, what are my options for software use? I have some experience using R but I am open to other options also.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s458157.html)?

Comment: @tchakravarty thanks. It seems Stata is the only up to date software on this topic. I know panel data regression and quantile regression but have little of this topic. Please suggest some beginner lessons given my background.

Comment: Your best practical introduction might be the [Stata Conference presentation](http://www.stata.com/meeting/boston14/abstracts/materials/boston14_powell.pdf) by David Powell, who is the developer of the `QRPD` module.

Comment: @tchakravarty The QREGPD module of Stata implements QRPD estimator developed in Powell(2015). Is there any implementation of this in any open-source software e.g. R.

Comment: I don't think so. You might want to consider writing your own implementation  using the Stata code as reference, or use the [Rstata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RStata/index.html) module, in case you have a Stata license.